# How to prevent people to see my password when I'm tytping it?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, mac, debian

How to prevent people to see my password when I'm tytping it ?
For example, if I type Canage01 and my sister look at me focus on my keyboard when I type it, she saw it.

Comment: Learn the Dvorak layout?

Comment: There isn't a real technical solution to this. It is, first and foremost, a behavioral issue, and must be first dealt with as one. That is, you need to talk to your sister, and you need to arrange your computer in a way that minimizes what others can see of your keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Don't type the password when your sister is looking?

Maybe use a password manager that autofills it, though it's unclear where you are typing the password.

You can also set a password that she won't understand, such as 5pY+vJe5-Y$er!bj{

Comment: Password manager don't work using windows login or mac login

Comment: Then just use a strong password (edited above with example). Something that even if she sees, she won't understand or remember. The only trick is that you have to remember it first!

Answer (score 0):

If you are a linux user, you can use a shoulder surfing protector like ssp package in AUR repos for Arch users or clone the repo directly from gitlab: https://gitlab.com/azratul/ssp . This works only for your linux based OS not a webpage. For that, I don't know about any solution.

Answer (score -1):

You could tap a bunch of random keys in addition to the password when you type it. So if someone was watching, to them, Canage01 would look like hCgaNin@ajgwe0641.

By tap, I mean lightly tap them, *act* like you're pressing the keys, but don't *actually* type them. Only actually type the characters in your password.

Comment: OK, then the sister wouldn't learn the password, but the op couldn't login either.  Not helpful.

Comment: I said "Tap" not "type". This way it would only _look_ like it was hCgaNin@ajgwe0641, as I originally stated.

Comment: @jimtut Edited to clarify.